# Converting 0 to a generic enum

Tags: vb.net, enums

I need to return a default enum from a function if it can't find the right one by description.

If I assume that the default enum is numbered 0, how can I do this?

VB won't let me convert 0 to T or even to `GetType(T)`.

I have tried:

```
Return CType(0, T)
Return CType(0, GetType(T))
Return DirectConvert(0, T)
```

etc...

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The default Enum depends upon the given Enum Type. If you are not specifying any type, the default type is Integer and thus the default enum zero (and the element, the one you asssociated with the zero position when defining it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *believe* that `Nothing` in VB works similar to `default(T)` in C#, so you should be able to use:

```
Return Nothing
```

That certainly works in my sample code:

```
Option Strict On

Imports System

Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()        
        Console.WriteLine(Foo(Of DayOfWeek)().ToString)
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Foo(Of T) () As T
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```